# Redirecting $_POST to another page

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, formit

I have "new account" form made with FormIt in ModX CMS. I want to redirect to another page with snippet that adds new user to the database, but FormIt removes $_POST array... How can I "move" that array to another page?

Answer (score 1):

All your POST variables are available to a formit post hook. just dump your code for adding to the database in a post hook. If it's successful formit will continue processing and redirect [or not] based on your snippit config. If you still need to redirect in a way that formit does not handle ~ you can use the sendRedirect() in your post hook & build the custom url with makeURL().

Answer (score -1):

Use a custom hook to set a placeholder, then pass that placeholder into the redirectParams.

```
[[!FormIt?&hooks=`mySetter,redirect`&redirectTo=`nextpage`&redirectParams=`{"product":"[[!+product.id]]"}`]]
```

Your 'customSetter' would look something like this

```
$product = $hook->getValue('productID');
$modx->setPlaceholder('product.id', $product);
return true;
```

This will take you to next page with query string of "?product="